# How to move around the GRID's children that have dynamic size

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm building a responsive webpage. Im using `Flexbox` and `Grid` for most of my layouts. Mostly, everything works ok, but I've run into some complex layouts and i'm wondering if using `Grid` is the way to go.

Basically, my design starts with a simple layout.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="g-cover">COVER</div>
    <div class="g-heading">HEADING</div>
    <div class="g-details">DETAILS</div>
    <div class="g-media">MEDIA</div>
    <div class="g-comment">COMMENT</div>
</div>


.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
```

That looks like this

[image]

So far so good. The problem is when I try to expand the page and move the grid's children around. I can't get it to work the way I want it... and im wondering if the `Grid` is the right tool for this.

For example, when I expand the page I want the `Grid` to look like this:

[image]

The grid's children height are dynamic, so sometimes it looks like this (notice the media is shorter):

[image]

Searching here, I've came up with this model that doesn't work...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .g-cover {
        grid-area: cover;
    }

    .g-heading {
        grid-area: heading;
    }

    .g-details {
        grid-area: details;
    }

    .g-media {
        grid-area: media;
    }

    .g-comment {
        grid-area: comment;
    }

    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 40% auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
        "cover heading"
        "cover media"
        "details media"
        ". comment"
    }
}
```

Am I going the wrong path? Is `Grid` the correct tool for what I'm trying to achieve. I just need guidance from the experts coz I've spent days trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Ok, so if I am correct, after reading the answer, `The width and height of grid items must be known in order to close gaps with surrounding items. So Grid, which is the best CSS has to offer for building a horizontally-flowing masonry layout, falls short in this case.` In other words, using pure GRID is not possible. Either I use javascript or the good old floating css options. Is this correct?

Comment: Try `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);` or `grid-auto-rows:1fr;` instead of `grid-template-rows: auto;` inside the media quesry